# How does the function process_frame(input_frame) receives its argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, parameter-passing, moviepy

The function **process_frame** is nested inside property **pipeline** which belongs to class **VehicleDetector** of  **utils.py** script. The property **pipeline** is called inside **main.py** script in function **process_video**.

Can someone explain me how does the function **process_frame** receives the argument **input_frame**.

*main.py*

```
import os
import glob
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

from helpers.ssd import SSD300
from helpers.utils import VehicleDetector

def process_images(detector):
    filenames = glob.glob('test_images/*.jpg')
    images = [np.asarray(Image.open(filename)) for filename in filenames]
    results = [detector.detect(img) for img in images]
    for i, img in enumerate(results):
        image = Image.fromarray(img)
        image.save('output_images/test{}.jpg'.format(i+1), 'JPEG')

def process_videos(detector):
    filenames = glob.glob('test_videos/*.mp4')
    for filename in filenames:
        print('Processing video {}'.format(filename))
        output = 'output_videos/' + os.path.basename(filename)
        clip = VideoFileClip(filename)
        clip = clip.fl_image(detector.pipeline)
        clip.write_videofile(output, audio=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_shape=(300, 300, 3)
    model = SSD300(input_shape, num_classes=VehicleDetector.NUM_CLASSES)
    model.load_weights('./weights_SSD300.hdf5', by_name=True)
    detector = VehicleDetector(model)

    process_images(detector)
    process_videos(detector)
```

*helpers/utils.py*

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import preprocess_input
from collections import deque
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

from .ssd_utils import BBoxUtility

class Vehicle:

    def __init__(self, location, size, type, n_history=50):
        self._type = type
        self._location = location
        self._size = size
        self._detected = True
        self._history = deque([], n_history)

    @property
    def types(self):
        return set(['Car', 'Motorbike', 'Bicycle', 'Bus'])

    def accept(self, location, size):
        self._location = location
        self._size = size
        self._detected = True

    def reject(self):
        self._detected = False

class VehicleDetector:
    voc_classes = ['Aeroplane', 'Bicycle', 'Bird', 'Boat', 'Bottle',
                   'Bus', 'Car', 'Cat', 'Chair', 'Cow', 'Diningtable',
                   'Dog', 'Horse', 'Motorbike', 'Person', 'Pottedplant',
                   'Sheep', 'Sofa', 'Train', 'Tvmonitor']

    NUM_CLASSES = len(voc_classes) + 1

    _threshold = 0.5

    def __init__(self, model, n_history=50):
        self._model = model
        self._bbox_util = BBoxUtility(self.NUM_CLASSES)

    @classmethod
    def draw_boxes(cls, img, results):
        draw_img = Image.fromarray(img)
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(draw_img, mode='RGBA')
        font = ImageFont.truetype("font/GillSans.ttc", 18)
        padding = 2

        # Parse the outputs.
        det_label = results[:, 0]
        det_conf = results[:, 1]
        det_xmin = results[:, 2]
        det_ymin = results[:, 3]
        det_xmax = results[:, 4]
        det_ymax = results[:, 5]

        # Get detections with confidence higher than threshold
        top_indices = [i for i, conf in enumerate(det_conf) if conf >= cls._threshold]

        top_conf = det_conf[top_indices]
        top_label_indices = det_label[top_indices].tolist()
        top_xmin = det_xmin[top_indices]
        top_ymin = det_ymin[top_indices]
        top_xmax = det_xmax[top_indices]
        top_ymax = det_ymax[top_indices]

        colors = {
            'Car': (255, 128, 0),
            'Bus': (0, 0, 255),
            'Motorbike': (128, 0, 255),
            'Bicycle': (255, 0, 128),
            'Person': (255, 0, 0)
        }

        for i in range(top_conf.shape[0]):
            xmin = int(round(top_xmin[i] * img.shape[1]))
            ymin = int(round(top_ymin[i] * img.shape[0]))
            xmax = int(round(top_xmax[i] * img.shape[1]))
            ymax = int(round(top_ymax[i] * img.shape[0]))
            score = top_conf[i]
            label = int(top_label_indices[i])
            label_name = cls.voc_classes[label - 1]
            display_text = '{} [{:0.2f}]'.format(label_name, score)
            if label_name in set(('Car', 'Bus', 'Motorbike', 'Bicycle', 'Person')):
                color = colors[label_name]
                size = draw.textsize(display_text, font)
                _draw_rectangle(draw, (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax), color)
                _draw_rectangle(draw, (xmin, ymin, xmin + size[0] + 2*padding, ymin - size[1] - 2*padding), None, fill=(*color, 40))
                draw.text((xmin + padding, ymin - size[1] - padding - 2), display_text, (255, 255, 255), font=font)

        return np.asarray(draw_img)

    def detect(self, input_img):
        inputs = []
        img = cv2.resize(input_img, (300, 300))
        img = image.img_to_array(img)
        inputs.append(img.copy())
        inputs = preprocess_input(np.array(inputs))
        inputs = np.expand_dims(inputs[0], axis=0)

        preds = self._model.predict(inputs, batch_size=1, verbose=0)
        results = self._bbox_util.detection_out(preds)

        final_img = self.draw_boxes(input_img, results[0])

        return final_img

    @property
    def pipeline(self):
        def process_frame(input_img):
            return self.detect(input_img)
        return process_frame

def _draw_rectangle(draw, corners, color, fill=None, thickness=3):
    start = -thickness//2
    end = start + thickness
    for i in range(start, end):
        points = [val + i for val in corners]
        draw.rectangle(points, outline=color, fill=fill)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `clip.fl_image(detector.pipeline)`.

According to the MoviePy docs, this is what `fl_image` does:

> Modifies the images of a clip by replacing the frame `get_frame(t)` by
>   another frame,  `image_func(get_frame(t))`

So, for each `frame`, MoviePy outputs `decorator.pipeline(frame)` instead of `frame`. Since `decorator.pipeline` has the `@property` decorator, it is actually equivalent to just `process_frame`, so `process_frame()` is applied to every frame.

Hopefully that answers your question.